# Why does a non-constant solution to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dt} = e^t(y-1)^2$ never have a *global maximum* on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, optimization

Explain why a non-constant solution to the following differential equation:

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}y}{\operatorname{d}t} = e^t(y-1)^2$$

cannot have a *global maximum* on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you mean $dy/dt$ in the DE? If so, it is clear then that if $y=1$ for any $t$, that $dy/dt=0$ and hence $y$ is constant. If not, then both $e^t$ and $(y-1)^2$ are always positive, so $\frac{dy}{dt}>0$ always.

Comment: At first glance, I would go for the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). Suppose $y^\prime(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ -- which implies $y(t_0)=1$.

Comment: Unless $y=1$, you could solve this to get $$y=1+\dfrac{1}{C-e^t}$$ for some constant $C$ and $$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{e^t}{(C-e^t)^2}$$ which is positive

Answer (score 0):

If a solution $y(t)$ has a global maximum, then for some $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{dy}{dt} = 0$, in which case $y(t_0)=1$.

Now, the problem is how do we show $y(t_0)=1$  implies $y(t)=1$ on all $\mathbb {R}$ without use of anything beyond what would be covered in a first year calculus course ^^.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your second paragraph: $e^t (y-1)^2$ is locally Lipschitz near $y=1$ so there is no non-uniqueness difficulty.

Comment: I'm saying the question should not require use of any theorem that's beyond a introductory calculus course. I think op does not know about Lipschitz.

Comment: But your second paragraph is just false; the locally Lipschitz version and the "$C^1$ on a rectangle" version both imply that.

Comment: So sorry, it's fixed now.